# Optimised Euclid's algorithm to compute the greatest common divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Could anyone show me how to compute the highest common factor (in this sample question it's $2117$ and $48053$) using optimised Euclid's algorithm (based on remainders of division)?

I don't know whether there is a easy way to learn there but I've got my exam in January and it's worth 5 marks so pretty important that I understand it :)

Showing me from scratch would be best, since I'm not the greatest at maths.

Comment: What is it that you do not understand about the Euclidean algorithm? It is perhaps the most described algorithm in existence, so it is hard to imagine that one could not find a suitable exposition.

Comment: I changed HCF to $\gcd$ (greatest common divisor) because people will recognize it immediately, something which doesn't happen with HCF.

Comment: Whether you should use the "optimized" version depends on whether you have a more efficient way of aquiring remainders available to you. Doing long division on paper with four digit denominators is not filed under "efficient" in my book. If I just have pen and paper available, I'd probably just guess that $48053 \approx 2117\cdot 23$, calculate the right-hand side, and work my way from there with the regular algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

- $48053 - (2117 \times 22) = 1479$
- $2117 - (1479 \times 1) = 638$
- $1479 - (638 \times 2) = 203$
- $638 - (203 \times 3) = 29$
- $203 - (29 \times 7) = 0$

For the values $2117$ and $48053$, the GCD = $29$

You can also try it with the [*Extended Euclidean Algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) or [*Euclidean Algorithm*](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

Comment: Well, I hope all goes great and you are done with this and get back to normal!!!